# jquery: password and confirm password

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

i am using jquery plugin for textboxes.. in my other textboxes the plugin works fine...but when i ma supplying details for some of my textboxes jquery doesn't work..

here is my code:

```
    jQuery("#Merchant_Registration").validate({
                rules: {
                    UserN: "required",
                    pass: {
                        required: true,
                        minlength: 5
                    },
                    confirm: {
                        minlength: 5,
                        equalTo: "#Password",
                    },
                    question: "required",
                    answer: "required"
                },
                success: function () {
                    xval = true;
                },
                messages: {
                    UserN: "Please enter your last name",
                    pass: {
                        required: "Provide a password",
                        minlength: "Password length at least 5 characters!"
                    },
                    confirm: {
                        minlength: "Password length at least 5 characters!",
                        equalTo: "Enter the same password as above"
                    },
                    question: "Please enter a security question",
                    answer: "Please enter answer to security question"
                }
            });

            if (jQuery("#Merchant_Registration").valid()) {
                return true;
            }
```

here is my mark up code:

```
<p>
                <label>Username:</label>
                <span class="field">
                <asp:TextBox ID="UserName" class="required" runat="server" name="UserN"></asp:TextBox>
                </span>
                </p>

                <p>
                <label>Password:</label>
                <span class="field">
                <asp:TextBox ID="Password" class="required" runat="server" name="pass"></asp:TextBox>
                </span>
                </p>

                <p>
                <label>Re-type Password:</label>
                <span class="field">
                <asp:TextBox ID="Password2" class="required" runat="server" name="confirm"></asp:TextBox>
                </span>
                </p>

                <p>
                <label>Security Question:</label>
                <span class="field">
                <asp:TextBox ID="SecurityQ" class="required" runat="server" name="question"></asp:TextBox>
                </span>
                </p>

                <p>
                <label>Security Answer:</label>
                <span class="field">
                <asp:TextBox ID="SecurityA" class="required" runat="server" name="answer"></asp:TextBox>
                </span>
                </p>
```

in my passwords field, it doesn't check whether the user input is the same...and doesn't show the message..

while the other textboxes, when clickthe next button the error that is displayed is "This field is required" and not the pre-set messages...

can some one help me..thank you..

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `name` attribute for the validator

Ex:

```
<form id="Merchant_Registration">
    <p>
        <label>Username:</label>
        <span class="field">
            <input ID="UserName" name="UserN"/>
        </span>
    </p>

    <p>
        <label>Password:</label>
        <span class="field">
            <input ID="Password" name="Password"/>
        </span>
    </p>

    <p>
        <label>Re-type Password:</label>
        <span class="field">
            <input ID="Password2" name="Password2"/>
        </span>
    </p>

    <p>
        <label>Security Question:</label>
        <span class="field">
            <input ID="SecurityQ" name="SecurityQ"/>
        </span>
    </p>

    <p>
        <label>Security Answer:</label>
        <span class="field">
            <input ID="SecurityA" name="SecurityA"/>
        </span>
    </p>
</form>
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xNLWz/2/)

Comment: @aianLee it was because I used `UserName` and `UserN`, check the updated sample

Comment: still the same...i changed the textbox's name to userN then called it in the jquery..but still the same...and the password and confirm passwords doesn't validate..

Comment: @aianLee did you check the attached demo, your markup should be similar

Comment: yes, i checked...i still cant figure out why it doesn't give the same output...i tried giving names for each of the textbox and calling the name in my jquery..but still the same...

Comment: @aianLee I'm not a ASP guy so I don't know the ASP syntax to do it, still can you share your updated code

Comment: @aianLee seems fine to me http://jsfiddle.net/xNLWz/3/ might be something specific to ASP, can you also check the browser console to see whether there is any errors